# d3.enter() is not a function

Tags: d3.js

When I log the selection returned after `.data(data)`, everything looks fine but when I try accessing `.enter()` I get an error:

> .enter() is not a function.

Here is my code:

```
drawIncidentOccurrenceChart = (data) => {
  // Dimensions of the graph
  var width = 900, height = 500;
  var svg =   d3.select('.ichart'); // svg element
  console.log(svg.append('g').selectAll('rect').data(data).enter());
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="chart">
  <svg class="ichart"></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: What is in `data`?

Comment: I have a list of objects. After a long struggle I think I found the problem. The react component was rendering the chart before the data was loaded.